# a set spans space

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

X is BANACH space and $T(t)_{t\geq0}$ un C$_{0}$-semigroupe sur X. 
U(x)= $int \{ y\in X, \exists (tn)\nearrow \infty \ limT_{tn}(x)=y\}$
My question is how to prove That if $U(x)\neq \emptyset$ then span(U(x))=X

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour.  You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context by stating what you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959 .

Comment: Every subspace of a Banach (or topological vector) space which has interior points is equal to the whole space.